# How to get column qualifier count..?

Tags: java, hbase, bigdata

In hbase we are inserting around 10 million data. We want to know how many column qualifier have been created so far.
Is any function available to check the total no of column qualifier created for the corresponding row in Hbase...?

Answer (score 0):

If MapReduce is acceptable, you should be able to map over the table using a Scan configured with a KeyOnlyFilter. Your mappers would then emit the qualifier and the reducers would simply dedupe (or alternatively, provide frequency counts, etc).